# How does the following pattern work const { Component } = React

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm watching the Redux videos found here: http://redux.js.org/ and I'm seeing the following pattern:

```
const { Component } = React;
```

How does this work?

Comment: what do you mean? it works because the language/transpiler/browser allow such syntax?

Comment: It's [object descructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). The result of the above statement is that a variable called `Component` now exists. NOTE: If you're familiar with Python it's a lot like tuple-unpacking.

```
var foo = {a: 1, b: 2};
var {a, b} = foo;

var bar = {c: 3, d: 4};
var {c} = bar;

console.log(a) => 1
console.log(b) => 2
console.log(c) => 3
```